# Set Text Not Working?

Tags: android

I have a set text that is supposed to update an amount donated. It is the total of all donations so far. In my donation activity when the donate button is pressed I update a number which holds the total donations to date. And then using a getter I get the number from the donation activity to my main activity and set the text to the number, but the number does not update. I have a feeling it might be because I don't refresh the text but I'm not sure. If it is then I don't know how to say that when ever the donate button is clicked to set the text in a diffrent activty. 
Donation activity:

```
public class DonationAmount extends AppCompatActivity {
public static double donateAmount = 0;
TextView donateAmountView;
Button donateButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_donation_amount);
    donateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.donate);
    donateAmountView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.donateAmount);
    donateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            donateAmount += Double.parseDouble(donateAmountView.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}
public static double getDonateAmount() {
    return donateAmount;
}
```

}

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView totalDonations;
private String mercheantKey, userCredentials;
private PaymentParams paymentParams;
private PayuConfig payuConfig;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    totalDonations = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalDonation);
    final FloatingActionButton donateButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    donateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent donateActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DonationAmount.class);
            startActivity(donateActivity);
            totalDonations.setText(Double.toString(DonationAmount.getDonateAmount()));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The issue is before call `setText` you'r redirecting to new activity.

Comment: First set the text and then redirect to next activity. @Archishmaan

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that i originally had it had it after the totalDonations = (TextView) .... but it didn't work so i moved it there

Comment: What gudgav ? Is this a part of question asked here ? @Piyush

Comment: You can't move there !

Comment: I'm confused it is before i redirect if not there then where should it be!

Comment: @Ankita Sorry ! It was by mistake.

Comment: The setText is before i move to the new activity i don't get where i'm supposed to put the setText statement

Comment: @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {        totalDonations.setText(Double.toString(DonationAmount.getDonateAmount()));
            Intent donateActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DonationAmount.class);
            startActivity(donateActivity);
            
        }
    });

Comment: On `donateAmount` btn click pass updated value of `donateAmount` using bundle to `MainActivity` and in `onCreate()` method set text to your textview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when button click call the method put setText before call the activity like bellow code

```
donateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
totalDonations.setText(Double.toString(DonationAmount.getDonateAmount()));
            Intent donateActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DonationAmount.class);
            startActivity(donateActivity);

        }
    });
```

Comment: for some reason the text take a large amount of time to update do you know how to fix this